# Find the answers of the two questions based on a rigorous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, implicit-differentiation

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function satisfying $$\sqrt[3]{f(x+y)}=\sqrt[3]{f(x)}+\sqrt[3]{f(y)}+1$$ $\forall \:\:x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f'(0)=3$

---

> If $h(x)=f(x)-x^3$ then find number of points where $y=h(|x|)$ is non derivable

> If $x_0$ is a solution of the equation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ then find the value of $$\cos^{-1}(\cos2x_0)+4\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\frac{x_0}{2}\right)$$

---

My initial thoughts were to differentiate the function partially with respect to $x$ and obtain a differential equation. Having said so, forming the differential equation is not helping me much and now I am stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a "rigorous function" (term used in your title)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{f(x)}$

$\Rightarrow g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y) + 1$

$\stackrel{h\neq 0}{\Rightarrow} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} = \frac{g(h) + 1}h$

$g$ is differentiable except at the points where $f(x) = 0$:

$\Rightarrow g(0) = -1$ and $g'(x) = g'(0)$

$g'(0) = \frac{f'(0)}{3\sqrt[3]{(f(0))^2}} = \frac 1{\sqrt[3]{(f(0))^2}}$

Since $g(0) = -1\Rightarrow f(0) = -1$, we get

$g'(0)= 1 \Rightarrow g(x) = x-1 \Rightarrow \boxed{f(x) = (x-1)^3}$

It follows, $h(x) = -3x^2+3x-1$. So $h(|x|)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ which is easy to check.

The solution $x_0$ of $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ must satisfy

$(x_0-1)^3 = x_0$ (Look at the graphs of $f$ and $f^{-1}$.)

Now, it's easily checked, that $x_0 \in (2,3)$.

$\Rightarrow 2x_0 \in (\pi,2\pi) \Rightarrow \cos^{-1}((\cos 2x_0)) = 2\pi - 2x_0$

$\Rightarrow \frac{x_0}2 \in (0,\frac{\pi}2) \Rightarrow \tan^{-1}(\tan \frac{x_0}2) = \frac{x_0}2$
Hence,
$$\cos^{-1}(\cos2x_0)+4\tan^{-1}\left(\tan\frac{x_0}{2}\right)= 2\pi - 2x_0 + 4\frac{x_0}2 = \boxed{2\pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $g(x) := \sqrt[3]{f(x)} + 1$.
Then,
$$
g(x+y) = \ldots ?
$$